# iOS , read title music ipod when the music is change

Tags: nsnotificationcenter, ipod, nsnotifications, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

i want to get title and artist name from ipod music currently music playing 
but i want when the music is changed i can detected and the UIlabel are change

here is the code :

```
 - (IBAction)getTitlemusic
{
   // MPMediaItem * currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;


    MPMediaItem * song = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
    NSString * album = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    NSString * title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString * artist = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];


    NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@", album,title,artist);

    songlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",album ];

    arttistlabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@",title,artist];


      [self performSelector:@selector(getTitlemusic) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0f];

}
```

i know the timer and delay isn't very good idea

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(getTitlemusic)
                                             name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                                           object:player];
[player beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

using this code